# unable to install podman on arm64 architecture

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, ppa, podman

I found this page saying arm64 version of podman
[https://launchpad.net/~projectatomic/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/16688612](https://launchpad.net/%7Eprojectatomic/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/16688612)

so I was following the steps under ubuntu on https://podman.io/getting-started/installation.html
i.e.

```
. /etc/os-release
echo "deb https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/kubic:/libcontainers:/stable/xUbuntu_${VERSION_ID}/ /" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/devel:kubic:libcontainers:stable.list
curl -L https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/kubic:/libcontainers:/stable/xUbuntu_${VERSION_ID}/Release.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

Log of `apt-get update`

```
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]       
Hit:4 http://repo.linaro.org/ubuntu/linaro-overlay stretch InRelease                
Get:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]     
Get:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]      
Hit:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:9 https://repos.influxdata.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                          
Hit:10 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/kubic:/libcontainers:/stable/xUbuntu_18.04  InRelease
Hit:11 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x bionic InRelease                        
Hit:8 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease         
Hit:12 http://apt.radxa.com/bionic bionic InRelease       
Get:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main arm64 DEP-11 Metadata [289 kB]
Get:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/universe arm64 DEP-11 Metadata [280 kB]
Get:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports/universe arm64 DEP-11 Metadata [9284 B]
Get:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/main arm64 DEP-11 Metadata [42.7 kB]
Get:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/universe arm64 DEP-11 Metadata [50.9 kB]
Fetched 925 kB in 5s (173 kB/s)                                                     
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

After that i tried upgrade.

```
sudo apt-get -y upgrade 
sudo apt-get -y install podman
```

but I keep getting package not located

```
$ sudo apt -y install podman
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package podman
```

Please help installing podman on arm64

Comment: Thank you for free advice @user535733 , i have added log of `apt update`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the Packages file at the source you added: Hit:10 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/kubic:/libcontainers:/stable/xUbuntu_18.04

(That's right, it's an ordinary URL, and you can open it in your browser.)

```
Package: podman
Version: 2.0.4~1
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: Lokesh Mandvekar <lsm5@fedoraproject.org>
Installed-Size: 73417
Depends: libseccomp2, libdevmapper1.02.1, libgpgme11, catatonit, conmon (>= 2.0.18~1), containers-common (>= 1.0.0~2), containernetworking-plugins (>= 0.8.6~1), runc | cri-o-runc, iptables, podman-plugins
Recommends: crun, slirp4netns, uidmap, varlink
Conflicts: podman-rootless
Filename: ./amd64/podman_2.0.4~1_amd64.deb
Size: 18709272
MD5sum: de24c24e4a2d990f244d41326e4afbce
SHA1: 22a610027770313e290f34a18f43a31b0f377810
SHA256: 7b7a579b4c77a6adde51235a6c77a3431d10323b4dd7378e52edf499bc709b27
Section: devel
Priority: optional
Homepage: https://github.com/containers/libpod.git
Description: Manage pods, containers and container images.
```

Bad news: Note that the "Architecture:" field is only "amd64" instead of "arm64" or "armhf". This source won't do anything for you. Remove it.

Now for the Good News:

```
$ rmadison podman
 podman | 2.0.4+dfsg2-1ubuntu1 | groovy/universe | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
```

Podman for arm64 and armhf has been added the normal Ubuntu repositories. It's currently in pre-release testing for 20.10. Feel free to help test it.

Comment: So package for 20.10 will work for 18.04 ?

Comment: No idea. Sometimes they do, sometimes they don't. Try it and see. Just remember that it's pre-release; it may have rough edges.

Comment: Few days back i tried to put latest unbound dns server on 18.04 but it didnt worked. I have never tried rmadison either

Comment: I installed devscripts thanks  can you please also show me how do i add groovy universe 20.10 to sources ?

Comment: rmadison is just a tool to search to package database; you don't need it unless you're going to be searching the database. DON'T add groovy sources -- they will destroy your bionic system irreparably. Download the one package and install it.

Comment: out of all the files in amd64 folder, which do i download and install from?